# Legend issue with ggplot graphic in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

[image]greetings!

Please I've plotted an empirical cumulative distribution with using ggplot and geom_line commands in R.
The variable plotted are the yields of three sorghum varieties "soubatimi", "tiandougou-coura" and "local" with the respective colour:green, blue and red.But I am not able to add legend to the chart with the respective colour set.
here is the dput(abc)

```
dput(abc)
structure(list(year = c(2018L, 2017L, 2020L), y_soubatimi = c(1614L, 
1665L, 2181L), prob_soub = c(0.047619048, 0.083333333, 0.041666667
), cum_prob_s = c(0.047619048, 0.130952381, 0.172619048), year.1 = c(2018L, 
2020L, 2017L), y_tiandougou_coura = c(1440L, 1475L, 1635L), prob_tc = c(0.047619048, 
0.041666667, 0.083333333), cum_prob_tc = c(0.047619048, 0.089285714, 
0.172619048), year.2 = c(2020L, 2018L, 2017L), y_local = c(916L, 
945L, 1080L), prob_loc = c(0.041666667, 0.047619048, 0.083333333
), cum_prob_loc = c(0.041666667, 0.089285714, 0.172619048)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

```
   ggplot()+geom_line(data=abc,aes(x=y_soubatimi),(stat="ecdf"),col="green")+
   geom_line(data=abc,aes(x=y_tiandougou_coura),(stat="ecdf"),col="blue")+
   geom_line(data=abc,aes(x=y_local),(stat="ecdf"),col="red")+
   labs(x= "Yields,kg/ha",y = "Probability")+
   scale_colour_discrete(name  = "", 
                      breaks= c("souba", "tiand", "loca"),
                      labels= c("y_soubatimi", "y_tiandougou_coura", "y_local")) +
   theme_bw() +
   theme(panel.grid.major.y = element_blank(), 
         axis.text.x = element_text(size=10), 
         axis.text.y = element_text(size=10), 
         legend.text =element_text(size=10))
```

Comment: Hey, The issue is because of the way you plotted you data. Can you share the abc dataframe? you can do dput(abc) and paste the result in your post

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding three `geom_line()`s and manually specifying the colour in each, try adding one `geom_line()` and setting the colour in the `aes()` based on values in a column. Since it looks your data is in 3 separate columns you'll likely need a call to `pivot_longer()`.

Here's an example that does what I think you're looking for using the data you provided:

```
library(tidyverse)

abc %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = c(y_soubatimi, y_tiandougou_coura, y_local)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_line(aes(x=value, colour = name),
            stat = "ecdf") +
  labs(x= "Yields,kg/ha",y = "Probability")
```

And the result:
[image: a ggplot ecdf]

It now has the legend matching species with colour. Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Many thanks, dear Christopher for your comments that are really useful. Please here is the dataset (ABC) meanwhile, I will try the command you suggested above and see.

Comment: The code you suggested above is working for each variable separately but my concern is how to put them together as one chart with a legend with each variety.
To explain more the data are 3 years time series for the three different varieties in each column. I think I can't set the colour to value but rather the variable name in each column it should have been defined a colour. Thank you

Comment: I've updated the answer to use the data you supplied. The new chart has all 3 species with a legend showing each variety. Let me know if you're looking for something else.

Comment: Greetings dear Christopher ! 
Many thanks for that great help. it is exactly what I wanted. So I think the code provided should work with the same kind of data I shared with because I need to build the same chart with income gained with the three varieties also. Kind regards

Comment: Great. If the answer works for you, don't forget to accept it and upvote.